# The method (reSize) not return vaule js

Tags: javascript, jquery

My script is

```
function test ()
    {
        this.reSize = function(iWidth, iHeight)
        {
            var iSize = new Array();
            var self = this;
            if (iWidth > 600 || iHeight > 600)
            {
                iWidth = Math.ceil(iWidth / 2);
                iHeight = Math.ceil(iHeight / 2);
                console.log(iWidth + ' resize ' + iHeight);
                self.reSize((iWidth / 2), (iHeight / 2));
            }
            else
            {
                iSize = {w:Math.ceil(iWidth), h:Math.ceil(iHeight)};
                console.log(iSize.w + ' tumbs ' + iSize.h);
                return iSize;
            }
        }// end reSize

        this.createDivImage = function()
        {
            var self = this;
            var iSizeTumbs = {};
            $('img.img-chat').unbind('click').click(function() {
                var src = $(this).attr('src');
                var sHtmlDiv = '';
                sHtmlDiv += '<div class="dialogs-img">';
                sHtmlDiv += '<div class="dialogs-img-close"><a href="#" class="circle ">x</a></div>';
                sHtmlDiv += '<div class="body-img">';
                sHtmlDiv += '<img src="' + src + '" class="body-img-zoom">';
                sHtmlDiv += '</div>';
                sHtmlDiv += '</div>';

                $('<img/>').attr('src', src).load(function()
                {
                    iSize = {w: this.width, h: this.height};
                    iSizeTumbs = self.reSize(iSize.w, iSize.h);
                    console.log(iSizeTumbs);
                });
            });
        }

    }

    var oTest = new test();
    oTest.createDivImage();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e4Hx5/5/

firebug:

> 800 resize 600 /e4Hx5/5/show/ (wiersz 31)
>
> 400 tumbs 300 /e4Hx5/5/show/ (wiersz 37)
>
> **undefined   /e4Hx5/5/show/ (wiersz 60)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that one of the execution paths (*the first case of your `if`*) inside the `reSize` method returns nothing..

You need to `return` something from that path as well.

So you need to `return self.reSize((iWidth / 2), (iHeight / 2));`

Here is your code updated: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/e4Hx5/6/

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a value, not just make a recursive call;

```
     if (iWidth > 600 || iHeight > 600) {
        iWidth = Math.ceil(iWidth / 2);
        iHeight = Math.ceil(iHeight / 2);
        console.log(iWidth + ' resize ' + iHeight);
        return self.reSize((iWidth / 2), (iHeight / 2));
    }
```

Also, in your code, you divide `iWidth` and `iHeight` twice, are you sure it's correct behavior?